# Maven copy the dependencies of independent Child project(jar) to parent project(war) WEB-INF/lib/?

Tags: java, spring, maven, plugins, pom.xml

> ```
> EAR 
> |
> |--WAR
> |
> |--Jar
> ```

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
<!--        <manifestFile> -->
<!--        src/main/java/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF -->
<!--        </manifestFile> -->
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Above code copies my jars to the `EAR` --> `lib/runtime` folder. I want to further move the dependencies of `jar` to `war`.

Comment: It does not make sense having an EAR as parent of WAR and JAR they should be siblings...with a common parent. Than the EAR can have a dependency to the JAR...

Comment: I am having this structure because the WAR is a third party and we own the jar so we are trying to keep the code independent. EAR is to package both

Comment: But a EAR is not a parent...so encourage you to change the structure which makes life easier.